# Entity Framework SaveChanges() not updating the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
var paymentAttempt = _auctionContext.PaymentAttempts.Where(o => o.Id == paymentAttemptId).SingleOrDefault();
if (paymentAttempt != null)
{
    paymentAttempt.PaymentAttemptStatusId = (int)PaymentAttemptStatus.Defunct;
    paymentAttempt.PaymentAttemptStatus = _auctionContext.PaymentAttemptStatuses.Where(pas => pas.Id == paymentAttempt.PaymentAttemptStatusId).First();

    var relevantWinningBidsTotalPrices = _auctionContext.GetWinningBidsTotalPricesForPaymentAttempt(paymentAttemptId).ToArray();

    foreach (var winningBid in relevantWinningBidsTotalPrices)
    {
        winningBid.Locked = false;
        _auctionContext.UpdateObject(winningBid);
    }
    _auctionContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the above code after

```
_auctionContext.SaveChanges();
```

is called `winningBid` is updated as expected but `paymentAttempt` isn't.  Why is this?  It is really frustrating.  There is no error either.  I would expect a failure to occur if there was a problem like EF wasn't tracking the object or something like that, but no such error is happening.

Comment: Use Attach to get your modified entity into context .Before you save. Context had no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning the differences between add, attach and entry: [entity framework core: difference between add, entry and attach methods/](https://gavilan.blog/2018/12/09/entity-framework-core-difference-between-add-entry-and-attach-methods/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because you need to pass the `paymentAttempt` object to your context, to let it know that it is an object that needs to be updated.

For example, assuming that `_auctionContext` is an instance of `DbContext`:

```
// any changes related to the paymentAttempt object 

_auctionContext.Entry(paymentAttempt).State = EntityState.Modified;

foreach (var winningBid in relevantWinningBidsTotalPrices)
{
   winningBid.Locked = false;
   _auctionContext.UpdateObject(winningBid);
}

_auctionContext.SaveChanges();
```

Another option is the `Attach` method:

```
_auctionContext.Attach(paymentAttempt);
_auctionContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(paymentAttempt, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: I don't have an Entry method.

Comment: 4.  We are using WCF Data Services on top of EF.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have `Entry` try adding:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

using System.Data.Entity;
```

then you may simply use:

```
_auctionContext.Entry(paymentAttempt).State = EntityState.Modified;
_auctionContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

I fell on this question but for a different problem. I discovered that if you call SaveChanges() on an object that hasn't been modified, EF will not update anything. This makes sense, but I needed the DB to be updated so that other users would see that a SaveChanges() had been executed, regardless of whether any fields had changed. To force an update without changing any fields:

```
    Dim entry As DbEntityEntry = entities.Entry(myentity)
    entry.State = Entity.EntityState.Modified
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but there's another explanation worth mentioning.  Even though your field name contains ID and may be set to autoincrement,  be sure to verify that you declared it in your table the primary key.